# Sexual intercourse duration of dogs and fertility

Tags: dogs, reproduction

My Pomeranian bitch and a male pin had sex today for 1 minute or so and his penis didn't get stuck in her. Does that imply that she hasn't been fertilized?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As thousands of young (human) involuntary mothers could probably tell you, you can't be sure.

Consult your vet, he'll be able to help you to determine the exact situation and what could or should possibly be done (as we don't know you dog's health status etc. either).